# How to integrate on-premise Power BI and PowerPoint

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to find a way to integrate on-premise PowerBI and PowerPoint. I want to get objects from a PowerBI dashboard and import them from PowerPoint. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: It's going to be snipping tool and pasting images onto the PowerPoint only.

Comment: Is there a deeper reason for that? I have been struggling with that too and I really do not understand the motivation why something that works in the cloud easily cannot be implemented for the on premise veresion